# Token indices sequence length error when using encode_plus method

Tags: nlp, tokenize, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I got a strange error when trying to encode question-answer pairs for BERT using the `encode_plus` method provided in the Transformers library.

I am using data from [this Kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/google-quest-challenge/data). Given a question title, question body and answer, the model must predict 30 values (regression problem). My goal is to get the following encoding as input to BERT:

[CLS] question_title question_body [SEP] answer [SEP]

However, when I try to use

```
tokenizer = transformers.BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
```

and encode only the second input from train.csv as follows:

```
inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(
            df_train["question_title"].values[1] + " " + df_train["question_body"].values[1], # first sequence to be encoded
            df_train["answer"].values[1], # second sequence to be encoded
            add_special_tokens=True, # [CLS] and 2x [SEP] 
            max_len = 512,
            pad_to_max_length=True
            )
```

I get the following error:

```
Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (46 > 512). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors
```

It says that the length of the token indices is longer than the specified maximum sequence length, but this is not true (as you can see, 46 is not > 512).

This happens for several of the rows in `df_train`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Which version of `transformers` are you using? Also, can you please post the full error message in the question, and not in the title?

Comment: I am using the latest public release (2.8.0) in Google Colab. Ok, will update it.

Answer (score 0):

The model 'bert-base-uncased' is not pre-trained to handle the long texts of [CLS] + Question + [SEP] + Context + [SEP]. Any other model from [Huggingface models](https://huggingface.co/models) dedicated especially for the squad question-answer datasets would handle the long sequence.

For example if I am using the ALBERT model, I would go for 'ktrapeznikov/albert-xlarge-v2-squad-v2' model.